# mysql select query with hierarchical function performance

Tags: mysql, database-performance

The following query is necessary for a project i am working on:

```
SELECT translations.id, GetInheritedTranslationTokenTranslationText(translations.id, translationtokens.id) AS inherited_text
FROM translations
JOIN translationtokens
LEFT JOIN translationtokentranslations translation_value ON translation_value.translationid = translations.id AND translation_value.translationtokenid = translationtokens.id
```

The GetInheritedTranslationTokenTranslationText is a user defined function, and is used to find a text value higher up in the tree (hierarchical structure is defined in the 'translations' table).

The used tables currently have the following number of records (will be many more in the future):

```
translations: 10
translationtokens: 866
translationtokentranslations: 870
```

The query above executes in +- 240 ms, and returns +- 12.000 records.
But when i add an `order by translations.id` or `group by` statement, the execution time is multiplied by 10, so around 2.4 seconds.

When i remove the custom user function, and use an `order by` statement, performance is good (+- 100 ms).

My question is: why would ordering the results take 2 seconds when the result set is unchanged. Why is the custom function having such bad effects on ordering on other columns? Is there a good workaround?

I know a workaround could be to wrap the query in a subquery and order the results, but that doesn't work for group by.

Comment: Surely, order by has another overhead of querying process.
The data have to sort before returning. Pure data can be caching on the server but your custom function cannot.

Comment: I have disabled SQL query cache. But isn't this strange:
- When I order by id in a regular query, and remove the custom function, the query is fast
- When I place the query in a subquery, and order by id, the query is fast
- When I order by id in the regular query with custom function ,the query is slow. The custom function shouldnt be relevant for the sorting, right?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  How fast/slow is the custom function?  Is `LEFT` needed?